# angularjs ng-model dynamic value used in filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I wanted to create filterable table with filter for each column so I generate the filters name dynamically using method I've found among stackoverflow:

And then I use the generated `search.<filtername>` values to filter the output in ng-repeat function like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: search">
    ...
</tr>
```

Everything works fine until I use nested property in dynamically generated search columns which looks like this: `merchant.name`. When I dump the value of search variable it shows:

```
{
  "merchant.name": "abc"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "merchant":
  {
    "name": "abc"
  }
}
```

and I think that that's the reason the filtering is not working for these nested properties because when I create the search inputs manually typing `search.merchant.name` the output json of `search` value looks fine and filter works properly.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to write my own custom filter for this case?

Comment: You have to do something like that: $scope.videos = ($scope.videos).map(JSON.parse);

Comment: AFAIK the `.map()` function can be used only on array objects. In this case I've got a JSON object, moreover that JSON.parse accepts string as an argument and this is not the case either.